# combine two variables in the same order in for loop unix

Tags: for-loop

It sounds simple but I can't do it in a simple way. In shell for loop, two vars

```
A=" 1 2 3 4"

B=" a b c d"
```

, try to print 1a 2b 3c 4d. Tried

```
A=" 1 2 3 4" 
B=" a b c d"
```

`for m in $A 
    for n in $B; 
       do echo $m$n done`.

The output is

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

for

```
l
in
a
b
c
d
e
```

Anyone can help this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$ A=(1 2 3 4); B=(a b c d); for i in $(seq 0 3); do echo ${A[$i]}${B[$i]}; done
1a
2b
3c
4d
```

Comment: Thank you all for helps. From tkocmathla codes, I got following code,  it worked out: A=(1 2 3 4); B=(a b c d);  for i in  0 1 2 3; do   echo ${A[$i]}${B[$i]}; done
1a  2b  3c  4d

Answer (score 0):

In your attempt, the for cases aren't closed with a ;, so it keeps interpreting words in your second for statement as cases for the first for statement.

Use instead:

```
A="1 2 3 4" 
B="a b c d" 
for m in $A ; do
    for n in $B ; do 
       echo $m$n
    done
done
```

Comment: Actually, this won't give you what you're actually looking for, it will give you 1a 1b 1c 1d, which is what it looks like you want from your code.